# jquery working on body but not on other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

This code works...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').css('background','black');
  });
```

but this code doesn't...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('thumb_slider').css('background','black');
  });
```

^^^the only thing I've changed in the whole code is the id attribute inside the parenthesis. Nothing else at all has been changed.

I do have an html element tag with id="thumb_slider" and it has text in it that I can see on the screen, but none of my jquery works when I reference an html tag or id other than the body. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want '#thumb_slider'. It's the difference between an id and an element name, i.e.:

```
$('#thumb_slider').css('background','black');
```

You select with jQuery in a very similar way to selecting with CSS, so:

- `body`, `div`, `p`, etc: select the elements with that name, i.e. of that *type*.
- `#this`, `#that`: select the element with that specific ID.
- `.lots` `.otherstuff`: select the element(s) with that class.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#thumb_slider').css('background','black');
```

You forgot the `#`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `.` or `#` in your selector, depending on if it is a class or an ID. There is no element named `thumb_slider` that matches your selector.

So it should probably be either:

```
$('#thumb_slider').css('background','black'); // If it is an ID
```

Or:

```
$('.thumb_slider').css('background','black'); // If it is a class
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you DO need `.` (dot) for class selectors and `#` for id selectors.

That said, your code should probably look like:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thumb_slider').css('background','black');
  });
```